# TreeView binding 2-depath ObservableCollection binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I follow this article: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/19341/wpf-tree-view-how-do-i-add-to-the-selected-item.html)

When I tested a new project is possible but I cannot adapt to my real project. 
I want to display treeview when I click a submit button with channel information.
This is my code below:

> .xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MCTv2.UI.LeftTreeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MCTv2.UI"
         xmlns:UIC="clr-namespace:MCTv2.UIController"
         xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:MCTv2.Modules.ActionDefinition"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         mc:Ignorable="d" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <UIC:AddChannelViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <UIC:AddChannelViewModel x:Key="avm"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding View}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <UIC:TreeViewBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ChannelObject}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Channel}">
                <Label Content="{Binding channelName}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

> ChannelObject(Model).cs

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using MCTv2.UIController;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MCTv2.Modules.ActionDefinition
{
    public class ChannelObject : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string ChannelName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<DeviceObject> DeviceObjects { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DeviceObject>();
    }

    public class DeviceObject : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }

        public UserTest userTests { get; set; } = new UserTest();
        public ConformanceTest confTests { get; set; } = new ConformanceTest();
    }

    public class ConformanceTest
    {
        public string FunctionCodeTest = "FunctionCodeTest";
    }

    public class UserTest
    {
        public string ReadCoilTest = "ReadCoilTest";
        //public string ReadDescreteTest { get; set; }
        //public string ReadHoldingRegisterTest { get; set; }
        //public string ReadInputRegisterTest { get; set; }
        //public string WriteSingleCoilTest { get; set; }
        //public string WriteSingleRegisterTest { get; set; }
        //public string WriteMultipleCoilTest { get; set; }
        //public string WriteMultipleRegisterTest { get; set; }
        //public string UserDefineTest { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> AddchannelViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using MCTv2.UI;
using MCTv2.UIController;
using MCTv2.UI.MainViewWindow;
using MCTv2.Modules.ActionDefinition;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;

namespace MCTv2.UIController
{
    public class AddChannelViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string channelName;
        private string numberofDev;

        public string Name
        {
            get => channelName;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ChannelObject> treelist = new ObservableCollection<ChannelObject>();
        public ObservableCollection<ChannelObject> View { get => treelist; }
        
        public ChannelObject SelectedItem { get; set; }

        private int nr = 1;
        private ChannelObject Channel
        {
            get => new ChannelObject()
            {
                ChannelName = channelName,
                DeviceObjects = new ObservableCollection<DeviceObject>()
                {
                    new DeviceObject()
                    {
                        DeviceName = $"device {numberofDev}",
                        confTests = new ConformanceTest(),
                        userTests = new UserTest()
                    },
                    new DeviceObject()
                    {
                        DeviceName = $"device {numberofDev+1}",
                        confTests = new ConformanceTest(),
                        userTests = new UserTest()
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        private DeviceObject device;
        private DeviceObject devs
        {
            get => device;
            set
            {
                new DeviceObject()
                {
                    DeviceName = $"device"
                };
            }
        }

        public AddChannelViewModel()
        {
            AddChannelCommand = new RelayCommand<object[]>(AddTreeNode);
            ClosePopupCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(ClosePopup);
        }

        private void AddTreeNode(object[] parameter)
        {
            #region parameter recieve

            channelName = parameter[0].ToString();
            if (channelName == null) return;
            numberofDev = parameter[1].ToString();
            if (numberofDev == null) return;

            if (parameter[2] != null)
            {
                var win = parameter[2] as Window;
                win.Close();
            }

            #endregion

            #region Set a Treeview items

            if (SelectedItem == null) treelist.Add(Channel); else SelectedItem.DeviceObjects.Add(devs);
            
            #endregion

        }

        private void ClosePopup(object parameter)
        {
            var win = parameter as Window;
            if (win != null) { win.Close(); }
        }

        public ICommand AddChannelCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ClosePopupCommand { get; set; }
    }

    public class TreeViewBehavior : Behavior<TreeView>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectedItemChanged;
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            var tv = sender as TreeView;
            if (tv == null) return;

            var vm = tv.DataContext as AddChannelViewModel;
            if (vm == null) return;

            vm.SelectedItem = tv.SelectedItem as ChannelObject;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my scenario:
(Sorry for my poor picture :L)

[image: UX scenario]

How can I control a TreeView in my project?

Comment: Please do not add tags (e.g. `WPF)`) to your question titles.

Comment: Okay. I'll change title.

Comment: I've already changed it. :) Note that you don't need to mention WPF in the title because you have tagged your question with both `[c#]` and `[wpf]`, so we know this is a C# question specifically relating to WPF from that.

Comment: Your setup should function, provided that the DataContext for the `LeftTreeView` user control is of type `AddChannelViewModel`. Not that bindings are case sensitive, so this code `<Label Content="{Binding channelName}"/>` will not work because the property you are binding to starts with a capital C, that is `ChannelName`. Other than that, what troubles are you having?

Comment: @mennowo Thanks reply. I'll check a `ViewModel`. Also, I found problem that popup window's add button `AddTreeNode` dose not work. I create a `Add` command then concatenate `MainViewModel.cs`. I think so... This is not right way.

Comment: Take care to organize you view models correctly, so you know for sure which ViewModel is bound to which View. In your case, you should have a separate ViewModel for the popup window and for the main UI (or the part of that UI where you display the tree view). As it is, this is not the case: the `AddChannelViewModel` is meant to be bound to the popup, but it also holds the `ObservableCollection` you wish to bind to the main view. Split this up and see if it gets you further.

Comment: @mennowo Thank you for comment. So you mean that Popup window Viewmodel is seperate from a AddChannelViewmodel. Okay. good I understand, but Add button work for a TreeView contents. In this way, How can I control a TreeView another Usercontrol ?

Comment: The `AddChannelViewModel` would seem to be the ViewModel that belongs to the popup view. However, this is up to you to decide. I would have the popup be a dialog, that somehow returns data to the VM that is bound to the treeview. Ie. you give the dialog an instance of `AddChannelViewModel`, store results in it and use those afterwards. Based on the results, add an entry to the collection bound to the tree view. Proceed from there.

Comment: @mennowo Thank you. I'll try your solution! Have a good day.